# Best practice for error handling in SwiftUI (MVVM)?

Tags: swiftui, mvvm, error-handling

Is there a best practice for handling errors in SwiftUI?

Let’s say you have a NetworkManager-class with methods that can throw. The NetworkManager-class uses some helper-classes with methods that also can throw.

Finally we have a ViewModel and a View. Do we rethrow all (important) errors forward until we reach the Viewmodel, where we catch and handle those errors and then present the error in a neat way to the View (ie via a @Published-property)? Is it ok/useful to rethrow errors from the ViewModel to the View and handle the errors in the View?

Is it bad practice to ”just” rethrow errors forward. Is it better to create custom errors and throw those instead? Like NetworkManagerError, MyHelperClassError and so on. Or maybe even MyAppError where all possible errors are defined?

Comment: Throw and present to the user a proper message

Comment: The problem with using view model instead of `.task` is you don't get a cancellation exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are correct till sending your error to your viewmodel. But from your viewmodel you should set some binding to your alert in your view. And as per value updated in binding your alert can get displayed.
Small example for your understanding.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
 .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert) {
            if viewModel.networkError {
                return Alert(
                    title: Text("Network Error"),
                    message: Text("Failed to fetch data from the server."),
                    dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
                        viewModel.dismissAlert()
                    }
                )
            } 
}
}
```

And this is how your view model may look like

```swift
// MARK: NO Import of UIKIT/SwiftUI here
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showAlert = false
    func performNetworkRequest() {
        do {
            // Perform the network request
            try NetworkClass.makeRequest()
            
            // Handle the successful network response
            // ...
        } catch let error as NetworkError {
            // Handle the specific network error
            showAlert = true
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you should pass information to display or hide your alert or any other UI in your view.
Hope this helps.